# Can aggregate initialization refer to a previous element in the aggregate?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is the following legal?

```
class Aggregate {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Class {
public:
    Class():
        m_aggregate{
            3,
            // Here, m_aggregate.a is fully constructed, but m_aggregate is not
            m_aggregate.a + 5
        } {
    }
    Aggregate m_aggregate;
};
```

Is it legal to use elements of an aggregate after their lifetime has begun, but before the completion of the constructor of the aggregate as a whole?

Testing with gcc 4.8.2 seems to behave correctly...

Comment: clang seems to give a warning for this, but gcc doesn't even if you explicitly enable `-Wuninitialized`

Comment: @remyabel: there was specific work on clang about uninitialized class members, but it may not have been repeated in gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that's legitimate. It is true that the elements of the braced list are initialized in order (i.e. the evaluation of list elements is sequenced, cf. 8.5.4/4), but the aggregate is only constructed *after* the list has been fully constructed. Cf. 8.5.1:

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the corresponding initializer-clause.

In order to copy-initialize from something, the original needs to exist first.

Comment: Would this same reasoning apply to calling a member function in the constructor that references previously initialized variables?

Comment: @DavidStone: Not quite, because the details of class initialization are actually specified. Inside the constructor, the object is "under construction", and you can use the class members to a limited extent, but you have to be *really* careful (e.g. don't call something that calls an external function on itself which in turn assumes a fully constructed object etc.).